# IOS Tab bar image size and resolution

Tags: ios, ios10, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I would like to add images to each one of my tab bar items. According to 
iOS Human Interface Guidelines the custom icons should have the following sizes:
[image]

In Xcode for each image set it is required to prepare 3 images with different resolutions (1x, 2x and 3x). In this guidelines it is not noted what must be the sizes for these images.
My question is according to ios guidelines what must be the sizes and resolutions for 1x, 2x and 3x images?

Comment: latest iPads are 2x, latest iPhones are 2x, plus model are 3x. Resolutions for 2x is min 50px x 50px, 3x is 75px x 75px. if you do the math 1x means 25px.

Comment: Hello.... @Vah.Sah There is no need to put `@1x` resolution images, you can keep it as blank. Because `@1x` images are used for non retina devices and now a days non retina devices are no more. So just fill only `@2x` and `@3x` images as per `Apple Inc.` guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

i think you should see this document 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

@1x : 25 x 25 (max: 27.67 x 27.67)

@2x : 50 x 50 (max: 56 x 56)

@3x : 75 x 75 (max: 83 x 83)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

50 x 50 px is 2x, 75 x 75 px is 3x, so 1x is 25 x 25 px